# Google Adwords Detecting "Malware" in Nonexistent Pages

Tags: php, security, google-ads-api, malware

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. Google Adwords is requiring that we remove malware from my client's website, and we finally got them to send us a list of which URLs are affected.

They listed three .html pages, none of which exist on my client's website because all of them are .php. I think they are URLs from the previous version of the site, which was removed from the server a couple years ago...

Can anybody point me in the right direction to get this resolved for my client?

FYI: hosting is through Fatcow.

Comment: Did you check all links on these pages and other pages on that domain? Google flags pages as malware that link to pages with malicious content...

Comment: Yes, that was step one but nobody was able to find anything. The issue is that Adwords is reporting malicious links being present on pages that do not exist in the first place..